# javascript - вложенные ajax запросы в цикле

Tags: javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте. Есть у меня вот такой код (это структура моего кода):

```
for (var x = 0; x < array1.length; x++){
(function(x) {
    $.ajax({
    url : "http://someurl1.ru/"+array1[x]+"/",
    async: false,
    success : function(someresult1){
        array2.length = 0;
        array3.length = 0;
        var br = someresult1.split('<br>');
        for (var b = 0; b < br.length-1; b++){
            var space = br[b].split(" ");
            array2.push(space[0]);
            array3.push(space[1]);
        }
        for (var v = 0; v < array2.length; v++){
        (function(v) {
            $.ajax({
            url : "http://someurl2.ru/"+array2[v]+"_"+array3[v]+"/",
            async: false,
            success : function(someresult2){
                if(JSON.stringify(someresult2).search(some_array[x]) != -1){
                $.ajax({
                url : "http://someurl3.ru/"+array2[v]+"/"+array3[v]+"/"+some_another_array[x]+"",
                async: false,
                success : function(someresult3){
                    array4.push(someresult3);
                }
                });
                }
            }
            });
            })(v);
        }
    }
    });
})(x);
}
```

Как видите он выполняет свою задачу в "лоб" (как написали в в другом моём вопросе). Это поистине так. И у меня вопрос как этот код переделать по уму ?
Что мне нужно, так это то, что бы все мои ajax запросы выполнялись по порядку. Сейчас всю структуру "держит" `async: false.` Без него все работает неправильно. А с ним все довольно неплохо, но интерфейс "виснет", ну и работает довольно медленно. Помогите облагородить этот код. Я выложил структуру кода, а не сам код, для более простого понимания моей проблемы. Как он в моём понимании должен срабатывать:

```
1. Берем элемент из 1 массива.
2. Формируем ссылку и отправляем запрос.
3. Получаем ответ и делаем нужные нам действия (разрезаем ответ и загоняем в массивы 2 и 3).
4. Формируем ссылку и отправляем запрос.
5. Получаем ответ и делаем нужные нам действия (проверяем совпадение ответа с элементом в массиве).
6. Если есть совпадение то формируем ссылку и отправляем запрос.
7. Получаем ответ.
8. И только теперь берем следующий элемент из 1 массива.
```

Я довольно много ответа прочитал по похожим вопросам. Везде предлагают вместо `async: false` и циклов `for`, использовать рекурсивный вызов функции из колбэка `success` и `jquery promise`. Но это везде предлагают там, где использовали либо запросы в цикле, либо нужно выполнять запросы по очереди. Но у меня ситуация когда я хочу выполнять запросы по очереди (и что бы они ждали друг друга) и это все еще и в цикле (+ у меня запросы вложенные друг в друга). Так что помогите знатоки.

Comment: Я так понял ты какой-то сайт парсишь? Почему не на сервере?

Comment: Начал писать этого "бота" уже давно теперь он очень разросся и переписывать его уже довольно сложно. Ну и суть тут даже не в этом наверное. Пока мне просто интересно как люди со скилом программирования выше моего могут решить такую задачу со вложенными запросами в цикле. Что бы я увидел "этикет" программирования что ли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо рекурсивного вызова колбэков удобнее использовать функцию [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) для свертки массива в промис, который будет содержать цепочку необходимых операций над элементами массива. Ваш код с использованием этого подхода будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
// пустой промис, к которому будут присоединяться дальнейшие операции
var init = $.Deferred();

// массив url, к которым нужно выполнить запрос 
var array1 = [ ... ];

// сворачиваем значения array1 в промис, одновременно запуская его на выполнение
// prevValue - промис, к которому будем присоединять присоединить обработку текущего url
// curUrl - текущий элемент массива
// curIndex - индекс элемента
var result = array1.reduce(function (prevValue, curUrl, curIndex) {
    return prevValue
        .then(function () {
            return $.ajax(curUrl);
        })
        .then(function (ajaxResult) {
            return /* формируем из ajaxResult вместо двух массивов array2, array3
             один массив из объектов и возвращаем его */;
        })
        .then(function (array23) {
            // сворачиваем array23 аналогично array1 в новый промис
            // можно вынести в отдельную функцию для читаемости
            var init2 = $.Deferred().resolve();
            return array23.reduce(function (prevValue2, curArray23Value) {
                return prevValue2
                    .then(function () {
                        return $.ajax(/* url из array23 */)
                    })
                    .then(function (ajaxResult2) {
                        if (JSON.stringify(ajaxResult2).search(some_array[curIndex]) != -1) {
                            return $.ajax(/* url из curArray23Value и some_another_array[curIndex] */);
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function (ajaxResult3) {
                        // если на предыдущем шаге запрос не выполнялся,
                        // ajaxResult3 будет undefined
                        if (ajaxResult3) {
                            array4.push(ajaxResult3);
                        }
                    });
            }, init2.promise());
        });
}, init.resolve().promise());

result.then(function () {
    // здесь можно использовать array4
});
```